# Induced $K$-theory maps between $C^*$ algebras.

Tags: functional-analysis, algebraic-topology, operator-theory, operator-algebras, k-theory

So here is a construction outlined in  [Higson's note on index theory, pg 46](http://folk.uio.no/rognes/higson/Book.pdf)

---

> Let $\mathcal{K}$ denote a $C^*$ algebra of graded compact operators on a graded hilbert space $H=H_0\oplus H_1$. 
>   Let $\mathcal{S}=C_0(\Bbb R)$.  Let $A$ and $B$ be (not necessarily unital) $C^*$-algebras.
>
> Let $\phi:\mathcal{S} \otimes A \rightarrow B \otimes \mathcal{K}$ be a $*$-algebra homomoprhism.
>
> We want to construction a $K$-theory map $\phi_*:K(A) \rightarrow K(B)$.

---

He argues the existence as follow, beginning with:

> Let $C$ be image of $\mathcal{S} \otimes A$ under $\phi$. Then we obtain homomoprhisms $\phi_{\mathcal{S}}, \phi_A$ of $\mathcal{S}$ and $A$ into the multiplier algebra of $C$.

How does this work? I do not see how this even follows from universal property of multiplier algebras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\phi\colon \mathcal{S}\otimes A\to C$ is non-degenerate, there exists a unique strictly continuous extension $\tilde \phi\colon M(\mathcal{S}\otimes A)\to M(C)$. Moreover, the universal property of the tensor product gives canonical maps $\iota_{\mathcal{S}}\colon\mathcal{S}\to M(\mathcal{S}\otimes A)$, $\iota_A\colon A\to M(\mathcal{S}\otimes A)$. The $\ast$-homomorphisms $\phi_{\mathcal{S}}$ and $\phi_A$ are given by the obvious compositions of the previous maps.

On a more technical level, the maps $\phi_{\mathcal{S}}$ and $\phi_A$ are given by
$$
\phi_{\mathcal{S}}(f)=\lim_\lambda \phi(f\otimes e_\lambda)\\
\phi_A(a)=\lim_j \phi(g_j\otimes a),
$$
where $(g_j)$ and $(e_\lambda)$ are approximate units for $\mathcal{S}$ and $A$ respectively and the limits are taken in the strict topology (of course one has to justify that they exist).

Comment: Thank you so much. Currently I only know the definition of multiplier algebra as given in nlab:  https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/multiplier+algebra , assuming its existence to.  It seems to me you are using a lot more results then I know. Is there a reference for the results you wrote ? i.e. 

1. How is $\tilde{\phi}$ constructed? 

2. What is the universal property of tensor product here? 

3. How does one obtian the formula for $\phi_S, \phi_A$.

Comment: Then you may want to take a look at Section II.7.3. in Blackadar's book on operator algebras (not the one about K-theory). I don't see an easy way to prove this statement using only the universal property of the multiplier algebra.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry, but I still don't see where the maps $i_S, i_A$ come from.

Comment: This is essentially contained in Theorem II.9.2.1. (remember that the multiplier algebra can be characterized as double centralizer of a non-degenerate faithful representation).

Comment: I am still working through certain definitions, hope you don't mind if i come back in future.

Comment: may you have a look at a new problem I have recently?